# Xamarin.Forms customizing action bar on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and on iOS I need to customize the top action bar.
In this case I need to remove the dark line between the top action bar and the content view below (see screen shot).
How can I do it ?

Thank you in advance!!

[image]

I did it here and it working:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            //Tab bar
            UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(247, 139, 43); 
            //Switch
            UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(247, 139, 43);
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------                    
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();            
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();                 
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Comment: just did it, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by either creating a custom Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
    namespaceiOS.Renderers
    {
        public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
        {

            public override void ViewDidLoad()
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad();

                this.NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
                this.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
             }
          }
     }
```

Or in your iOS project, in AppDelegate method "FinishedLaunching" you could use the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/) API to style your application across the board.

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Comment: is this the only way? there are no settings or styles I can set on Xamarin.iOS project like I did for Android project ?

Comment: Yes it helps!! I did it in AppDelegate.cs inside FinishedLaunching as I posted on my comment above and it's working. Is it ok or I have to do it inside "DidFinishLaunching". If this is the case do you know how to put inside "DidFinishLaunching" ? Thanks!!!

Comment: DidFinishLaunching was just a Typo on my part. I updated to reflect the correct method name.